# jQuery Mobile encodes my Hebrew URLs

Tags: jquery-mobile, unicode, encode, hebrew

I have a site written in Hebrew which contains some URLs with hebrew words and I'm using jQuery Mobile with the RTL plugin.

I have a problem: that jQuery plugin insists on encoding my hebrew URLs to something like: %E2%D5%D2%EA-%EA%E4%D5%D7%D9%DD.

It makes a lot of problems since my CMS can't figure them out and then I can't use techniques like going back in history. Therefore is there a way to decode those URLs or even better, make jQuery not encode them by default?

Thank you.

Comment: At what point does the plugin encode it like this? It makes no sense since the encoding is Mac Hebrew and URL encoding must be in UTF-8... but there is also no code in the plugin source code to encode as Mac Hebrew.

Comment: It happens every time jQuery encounters a hebrew link it should open in AJAX mode. I tested in none AJAX mode (set the links data-ajax attribute to false) and it opened the hebrew links without encoding them.

Comment: What server are you using? You cannot just put Hebrew characters in a link, they must be URL encoded.

Comment: I'm on a shared host running Apache version 2.2.23. However I don't think it's Server related or Joomla! (My CMS) related since when I enter a Hebrew URL without AJAX it works just fine (The URL is not encoded in any way). I do manage to open AJAX pages but jQuery fetches the page content and simply overrides the previous page and then sets the browser URL to the encoded Hebrew URL. The options I think about are that the server returns an encoded URL and jQuery uses it or jQuery encodes the URL found in the <a> tag.

Comment: I think i'm on to something, when I enter in the console: jQuery.ajaxSettings.url, I receive the following URL: mydomainname/site/component/k2/item/776-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%92%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A5-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%92%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A1-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%98%D7%9F,-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94,-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%A1,-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95%D7%96